# Array suma de ventas por dias en php desde mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta Mysql para calcular el total de ventas realizadas en un día y guardarlo en un Array que contenga todos los días del mes para después cargarlo dentro de chartist.js y crear una gráfica.

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++ )
    {
        $año    = date('Y');
        $mes    = date('m');
        $dia    = $i;

        $fechaInicio    = $año . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia . ' 00:00:00';
        $fechaFin       = $año . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia . ' 23:59:59';

        $statement = "SELECT SUM(pr_gadgets_information.cash) as total FROM pr_gadgets_information WHERE pr_gadgets_information.created >= '$fechaInicio' && pr_gadgets_information.created <= '$fechaFin'";

        $query = $this->db->query($statement);

        while ($salida = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
        {
            $salida[] = $salida;
        } 
        return $salida;
     }
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error: 
Message: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

¿alguna sugerencia de donde viene el fallo? Estoy usando Codeigniter

Acabo de realizar el siguiente cambio:

```
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++ )
        {
            $año    = date('Y');
            $mes    = date('m');
            $dia    = $i;

            $fechaInicio    = $año . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia . ' 00:00:00';
            $fechaFin       = $año . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dia . ' 23:59:59';

            $statement = "SELECT SUM(pr_gadgets_information.cash) as total FROM pr_gadgets_information WHERE pr_gadgets_information.created >= '$fechaInicio' && pr_gadgets_information.created <= '$fechaFin'";

            $query = $this->db->query($statement);

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                if($row['total'] == null)
                {
                    $resultado[] = 0; 
                }else {
                    $resultado[] = $row['total'];
                }
            }

        }
        //var_dump($resultado);
        return $resultado;
```

Realizando var_dump($row); obtengo las respuesta que busco y ademas gestiono las columnas que son nulo cambiandolas a 0 ahora bien cuando trato de mostrar los datos con el return $resultado obtengo el siguiente error:
Message: Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: probaste que ese string de query funcione en tu base de datos? digo, si lo imprimes y copias en mysql?

Comment: si, me devuelve esto: 
total
2110

Comment: ¿Por qué le pasas `$query` a `fetch_object()`? Mira el [ejemplo del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php): `if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

    /* obtener el array de objetos */
    while ($obj = $resultado->fetch_object()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }
`

Comment: le paso $query porque es donde estoy guardando el resultado de la consulta según la nomenclatura de Codeigniter:

 $query = $this->db->query($statement);

Comment: Ya, pero para leer, no debería ser: `$salida[]=$salida->total;`?

Comment: en eso tienes razón pero con ese cambio sigue mostrando el mismo error

Comment: Al parecer en el modo procedural: `$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ...";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }` **hay que pasar la conexión y la cadena SQL**. MySQLi es para mi siempre confuso.

Comment: Si, tienes razón siguiendo el procedimiento normal seria tal y como dices. Pero al usar "Codeigniter" añade un helper el cual previa configuración con tu base de datos lo único que tienes que hacer es llamar los metodos asociados como por ejemplo:

                $query = $this->db->query($statement);

yo uso "$statement" para escribir mis propias consultas sin acudir a estos métodos que en ocasiones son un poco liosos y despues ejecutar la consulta con $this->db->query

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, el problema es al mostrar `$resultado`, y en parte es normal es un array no estas indicando que parte del array quieres mostrar, si quieres sumar todos lo elementos del array puedes hacer lo siguente `echo array_sum($resultado);` por ciero la parte del for para las fechas me parece muy fea, sin ofender.

Comment: Y como la harías?